# Result Code: 0x80070003 while creating a folder

Tags: 2010

I have an issue while creating a folder via a webservice.

> The operation failed because an unexpected error occurred. (Result Code: 0x80070003)

Any idea about the error code?
Using SP 2010 web services

Comment: Please check event logs on SharePoint and database server and report back with your findings

Comment: I dont anything about SP i am doing java code web service call on wsdl using SOAP..

Comment: Can you provide the API name and the parameters you are passing to the API.

Comment: spring-ws-core schemas-unkown

Comment: SCK, that is the type of information that is great to add to your post. The API:s you are using, and how you are using them (meaning code examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error /Result Code 0x80070003 means **"The system cannot find the path specified"**.

Please make sure you are passing the correct path / URL while creating the Folder. You can test the path before creating the folder via your code logic.

Comment: thats perfect answer. it was double space between words which caused the URL went wrong..